# Display a png (or ico) as icon in the windows taskbar

Tags: python-3.x, windows, image, tkinter, icons

I have an image and I would like that to make my python program (tkinter GUI) visualize it as an icon in the Windows taskbar, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot do that when the file is a `.py`. It needs to be an executable.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/

Open any terminal (like cmd, WT or PS) and along with the other pyinstaller flags, add `--icon="path_to_icon.ico"`

Example:

```
pyinstaller my_program.py --icon="icon.ico"
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file="icon.png")
root.iconphoto(True, icon)
```

Note that this only handles 1 of the 2 icon locations, the icon for the file needs to be set in windows explorer.

Comment: Yep, I was already using It for the icon of the window, that wasn't the problem, It's the window task bar that I'm not able to set through the code.